# Error: "an object representing an expression must have exactly one field" while using expr in find()

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My output for the `db.dummy.find(query).count()` should be **2** but I am getting the following error.

Please note the "mark" field is in an array and has "string value" therefore used `$map` because using `$convert` for array throws conversion error.

```
db.dummy.find({
  $expr: {
    $project: {
      adjustedGrades: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data.mark",
          as: "grade",
          in: {
            $lte: [
              {
                $toInt: "$$grade"
              },
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    $match: {
      adjustedGrades: {
        $eq: true
      }
    }
  }
}).count()
```

Error:

```
 error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $project: { adjustedGrades: { $map: { input: \"$data.mark\", as: \"grade\", in: { $lte: [ { $toInt: \"$$grade\" }, 5.0 ] } } } }, $match: { adjustedGrades: { $eq: true } } }",
        "code" : 15983,
        "codeName" : "Location15983"}
```

**Collection:**

```
{ "_id" : "1_0", "data" : [ { "Class" : "DUMMY1", "mark" : "5" } ] }

{ "_id" : "2_0", "data" : [ { "Class" : "DUMMY2", "mark" : "3" } ] }

{ "_id" : "3_0", "data" : [ { "Class" : "DUMMY3", "mark" : "9" } ] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from mongoDB community, I was able to get the solution for conversion and comparison of values in an array that can be used inside db.collection.find() rather than aggregate().

```
>db.testcol.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$allElementsTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$data",
        "as": "d",
        "in": {
          "$gt": [
            {
              "$toDouble": "$$d.userDL"
            },
            5
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
Output: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB Documentation,

> $expr:
> Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

$expr has the following syntax:

```
{ $expr: { <expression> } }
```

The arguments can be any valid aggregation [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions). For more information, see [Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions).

`$project` cannot be used inside `$expr`

In order to achieve your use case, you can use aggregation framework:

```
db.dummy.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      adjustedGrades: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "grade",
          in: {
            $lte: [
              {
                $toInt: "$$grade.mark"
              },
              5
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      adjustedGrades: {
        $eq: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground:Using aggregate()](https://mongoplayground.net/p/24w9FO1udNa)

If you don't want to use aggregation framework, try the following method:

First do the conversion of string to Int using parseInt() :

```
db.dummy.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc.data.forEach(function(d) {
d.mark=parseInt(d.mark);    })
    db.dummy.save(doc); 
})
```

And then run the find() query:

```
db.dummy.find({
  "data.mark": {
    $lte: 5
  }
}).count()
```

Comment: Hi Tiya, i want to be able to do this same using find() and not aggregate(). i have gone through the docs and as far as i understand, I think it should be possible using $expr but i am not getting how. plz correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can simply do this using the following query without even using $expr: ```db.dummy.find({
  "data.mark": {
    $lte: "5"
  }
}).count()```

Comment: >db.dummy.find({   "data.mark": {     $lte: "10"   } }).count(). When I check for $lte : 10 it gives output 0 as its doing a lexicographical kind of conversion. So conversion is necessary. Also normal $convert won't work as the field is in an array, so it throws conversion error. So $unwind with $match or $map with $match does the work but i want to be able to do it using find() and not aggregate() using $expr

Comment: Yes, You are right! conversion is necessary. I have updated the answer to do the conversion using ParseInt() and then run the find() query.

Comment: Is it possible to do the parseInt() and $lte within find() itself and without modifying the data? The query should do the conversion only for the finding the correct docs but not actually modify the docs. I don't necessarily want to use the $project in my original query or add a new field. Just that, within find() itself the conversion and comparison should come and it should return the corresponding docs.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

> db.getCollection("dummy").find({ "data.0. mark": { $lte: "5" } }, {})